# sql_clause with UpdateCursor does not honor DISTINCT like SearchCursor does in ArcGIS Pro 3.2

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, distinct, sql-clause

Using ArcGIS Pro 3.2

Here is the SearchCursor with sql_clause

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('Buildings', "type", sql_clause=("DISTINCT type", None)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])
office
church
retail
residential
commercial
public
```

and the UpdateCursor with sql_clause

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('Buildings', "type", sql_clause=("DISTINCT type", None)) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print(row[0])

church
commercial
residential
commercial
commercial
commercial
commercial
retail
church
commercial
retail
commercial
retail
...
```

**UpdateCursor does not honor the DISTINCT sql_clause like the SearchCursor does. Why?**

I have tried adding in extra fields like the example below such as ["OID@", "type"]

There is an example in the [Esri docs](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(
        in_features, 
        ["OID@", "STREET_NAME"], 
        sql_clause=("DISTINCT STREET_NAME", None)
) as cur:
```

Comment: Yes, the example is there, but I really have my doubts this would work. I mean, which records do you expect to get updated when a distinct clause is used? My guess is that the example is copied from the SearchCursor and never checked.

Comment: I think @Berend has hit the nail on the head, even if it did work which rows would you update...

Comment: I believe that you need to declare the field names or in_features. If you continue in the ESRI help docs there are references to the features. I.e. something like 
 -- arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_features, ['Buildings', "type"], sql_clause=("DISTINCT type", None)) as cursor

Comment: I expected it to return the same as the SearchCursor in terms of getting the distinct rows but not allow an update based what was returned. It is a read/write tool afterall. Things should work they way they say they should lol!! Definitely a copy paste job from the SearchCursor. Who's head in Esri should roll for this monstrosity? :D